# System is unusably sluggish, help me find out why

Tags: graphic-drivers, display, graphics

I just installed Freya on an old Pavillion Slimline with a Pentium E2140 Dual Core 1,6 Ghz, 2GB of RAM and a Radeon HD2350.

I know it's not the ultimate state of art PC, but I thought it was enough for Elementary OS and Pantheon DE, which I found amazingly fast on just slightly better machines. But in the end I found myself with an incredibly slow OS, not usable at all. System animations take forever to end, I disabled animations with elementary-tweaks but they are still taking the same time. Scrolling on the browser is sluggish and watching a YouTube video is impossible since it hardly displays a couple of frames a second.

Seems to me a graphics card issue, but the system doesn't show me any proprietary drivers available to install, and (in Info) is perfectly able to tell me what card I'm on, so doesn't seem to me like I'm using generic drivers or something.

The processor supports 64-bit, so I installed the 64-bit version, may this be a problem?

Comment: I doubt that this is the problem. It is more likely that Tweaks has set something silly in the animations and it is interfering. This has happened in the past. What was it like on default settings, before you installed Tweaks?

Comment: Perhaps try 0.3.2 on a USB and see if it runs better.

Comment: Sorry to tell, but your computer isn't good enough to run elementaryOS well. I'm currently in an Intel Celeron CPU @ 2.8GHz, 1.5 GB of RAM and a GeForce 6200. I tried elementaryOS from USB and it ran very badly (not unusable, but bad). You only have a 1.6 GHz CPU, which is not exactly good. Stick with Xubuntu/Lubuntu and be happy (I'm currently in Xubuntu 14.04 and it runs smooth as hell)!

Comment: @Lewis Goddard It actually got a bit better disabling animations with tweaks, it was equally if not more sluggish before installing it. Can't try from USB because this PC's BIOS doesn't boot from USB.

Comment: @Eduardo Cola Yes, I'm thinking about giving up and switch to Xubuntu/Lubuntu, but I don't know how to do this without compromising GRUB and preventing it to boot Windows partition. In my experience if I format the partition with the linux distro that created the dual boot all I get is a GRUB recovery command line, with no chance to access to any system installed. Anyway, it's a pity, I like the hell outta Elementary but right now I'm forced to stick with Windows on every other machine I have.

Comment: If you do everything correctly GRUB will be overriden by Xubuntu's installation.

Comment: Nope. In the end, graphics drivers is just what seems to be wrong. Xubuntu and Lubuntu are more responsive indeed, but still I get relevant problems. General screen tearing, sloppy graphic response to moving Windows, scrolling in menus or in the browser, impossibility to watch a streaming video properly. But the system is fast, so I don't quite see any other possibile issue.